# How can I extract various tables from Wikipedia using R?

Tags: r

I have the next link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prime_ministers_of_Spain

I'm trying to extract the information about Prime Ministers but it gives a table of data without any apparent order.

This is currently the code that I am using

```
library(XML)
library(httr)

url   = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_prime_ministers_of_Spain"
url <- GET(url)
datos = readHTMLTable(rawToChar(url$content), header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)
tabla2= datos[[2]]
```

Comment: I think this blog will answer your question: https://medium.com/@kyleake/wikipedia-data-scraping-with-r-rvest-in-action-3c419db9af2d

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Selenium. Through Selenium API you can access all functionalities of the DOM.Prior I have used urlib library in Python but it didn't help if the page uses a lot of functionality thus the DOM always changes.